# Entity Framework Web API - Get related entities using Foreign Key value

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I have two tables `Round` and `Game`. A round has many games, and I'd like to get all of the games of a round using a Web API.

Here are my classes (simplified for the sake of this question)

```
namespace DataLayer.Entities
{
    [Table("Games")]
    public class Game : IEntity
    {   
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int PlayerOneId { get; set; }
        public int PlayerTwoId { get; set; }
        public Guid RoundId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RoundId")]
        public Round Parent { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace DataLayer.Entities
    {
      [Table("Rounds")]
      public class Round
      {     
         public ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }          
         public Guid Id { get; set; }
         public bool HasStarted { get; set; }
         public DateTime TimeStarted { get; set; }
         public int RoundNumber { get; set; }
       }
    }
```

I'd like to be able to pass in a round ID using Entity Framework and get all of the Games from that round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have lazy loading enabled, `include` the games contained in the round. If lazy loading is enabled, no `include` is needed.

The `Games` can be accessed by their navigation property (assuming the relationship is set up correctly in the EF Model).

```
Guid roundId;    
var roundWithGames = dbContext.Rounds.Include(r => r.Games).SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == roundId);
if (roundWithGames == null) { throw new ArgumentException(nameof(roundId)); }
var gamesOfRound = roundWithGames.Games;
```